# Correcting unfinished function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix

I should correct unfinished function Rfun() but I haven't managed to find all of the problems.

```
Rfun(N){
  A=matrix(0,nrow=50,ncol=300)
  t=c(0:30,0:-30)
  for(j in 1:50)
    x=N[j,]
    y=cumsum(x)
    for(i in 1:300){
     A[j,i]=y[i]/3
    }
  }
  return(A)
}
```

Comment: That's not how you define a function in R. You need to do `Rfun <- function(N){` as the first line. Also, you first `for` loop does not have an opening curly brace. The function seems to work if you make these changes. However, these are basic typos and I am voting to close the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you didn't precise what the function should do, let me help you with what is apparently false to me:

1. This is not how you define a function in R you need to write `Rfun = function(N){}`.
2. The `return(A)` should be inside the function. Therefore you should remove one parenthesis.
3. the variable `t` is not used at all.